# Can't Install Windows 2008 R2 on Lenovo Laptop With SSD

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, compact-disc

I am trying to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on a new Lenovo X201 or T410 laptop.

Setup halts with the following pop-up:

> A required CD/DVD device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.
>
> Note: If the windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive you can safely remove it for this step.

The CD drive is obviously working, as it's booting from CD to get to this point.

The only thing I can think is that it is to do with the fact they have SSD disks in - but that's just a guess.

(Edit - One extra thing that may or may not be relevant: it's the 64 bit version of Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Does the installer recognize the SSD disk on the drive selection screen, or is it blank?

Comment: That's the weird thing. Yes - you can browse the existing disk content, but it still gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the exact same message when installing Windows Server 2008 R2.  I tried looking for drivers but could never get it past this screen.  I finally ended up just re-downloading the image from MSDN and re-burning the installation media.  After I got the new media it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the O.S. setup is booting from the CD-ROM drive doesn't necessarily mean the O.S. will be able to use it, as it's handled by the computer's BIOS while booting, but the O.S. could not have the proper drivers for it when it starts and has to manage hardware on its own.

You should have a look on the vendor site and see if there are available drivers for the onboard controller and/or for the CD-ROM drive. This link should help you:

http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-70656

If you really can't get it to work, try to install Windows from a bootables USB media; to create it, you only need to format it with the NTFS filesystem in a Windows Vista or Windows 7 system, and then copy the whole content of the Windows installation media on it.